# find size of file in file upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to size of file in file upload control.
I am getting error in Internet Explorer. But This is code working in other browser.
 Following code

```
var fuDocument = document.getElementById('<%= fupAttachment.ClientID %>');
  var file = fuDocument.files[0];
            if (file != null) {
                var fileSize = file.size;
}
```

error 'files.0' is null or not an object

Comment: Use IE10, IE<=9 doesn't support the file api

Comment: Any other code which support IE?

Comment: @Jd30814: I provided some code that should support IE - did you get a chance to test it, and if so: is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is to use those good ol' ActiveX objects:

```
var axFile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fileObj = axFile.getFile(document.getElementById('<%= fupAttachment.ClientID %>').value);
var fileSize = {bytes: fileObj.size,
                kBytes: Math.round(fileObj.size/1024),
                mBytes: Math.round((fileObj.size/1024)/1024)};
```

That should offer support for older versions of IE, the full version *could* look something like:

```
var axFile, fileSize, 
fuDocument = document.getElementById('<%= fupAttachment.ClientID %>');
if (fuDocument.files)
{
    fileSize = fuDocument.files[0].size || 0;//default value = 0
}
else
{
    axFile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fileSize = (axFile.getFile(fuDocument.value) || {size:0}).size;//default to object literal, with size: 0 property --> avoids errors, and defaults to size value of zero
}
return fileSize;//console.log, alert... whatever you want
```

Comment: This line is returning null object. `var axFile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");`. Can you please help. My browser is FF.

Comment: @SMC: That'll be impossible, [check the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086761/alternative-for-the-activex-object-for-the-other-browsers-excluding-ie/15087300#15087300).