# Alternative for the ActiveX object for the other browsers excluding IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Can anyone help me as i am stuck in creating a file(temporary) with extension(say .csv) in the local disk, i tried using ActiveX object but it works fine only in internet explorer,got a error when i tried with other browsers. By googling i got to know ActiveX works only in IE so it produces error when its tried in different browser.

```
    var fso, f1;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f1 = fso.GetFile("c:\\test.txt");
    alert(f1);
```

Can anyone suggest me with the alternative which can be very useful to.

Comment: There's no corresponding feature in other browsers. The nearest you can find is probably [HTML5 localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i want to store the data that comes from the web service through ajax in a file created in the local disk using javascript.

Comment: Can I ask why as there may be a better option? If you are calling a web service, I assume you have access to some server side code / scripting where this task may be better suited and be truly cross browser compatible.

Comment: i want to store the file with .csv extension which can help to open this file using notepad,excel etc. Can you suggest me if there are any better option?

Comment: I have added an answer with more inforamtion. If you need anything else, post a comment against the answer (to avoid bloating it up here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other posts cover all the information about storing to the local machine using Html 5 so I won't go into any more detail about that but this is only going to work on Html 5 compatible browsers (although most browsers are Html 5 compatible now, I don't know your project requirements).

Another alternative would be to create / save the file using server side code (ASP.NET, PHP etc) and then provide a link to the user so they can download the file. You can still save this as a .csv file so that the user can open it in Excel after they have downloaded it.

Edit:

What I would do is change your web service so that it saves the file to disc (more info: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)). Then instead of returning the file from the web service, return the Url to download it instead. You can then redirect the user to that link using JS.

Comment: Thanks,Can you provide some link, i am using vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that browser implementations of ECMAScript (JavaScript) *don't allow you to write to the clients' disk*. Microsoft reverse-engineered JavaScript, and dubbed it *JScript*. Though the base is the same, MS added those ActiveX objects, and a compiler (JScript can be compiled, yes).

In short, JScript can be used for more than just browser tasks, so MS provided ActiveX objects to enable some form of I/O. The only thing you can do on browsers *other* than IE, is using HTML5's new DOM Storage objects. Teemu provided a link to the documentation for that

Comment: Good answer. I'd simply say it is not possible to do this in non-ActiveX-browsers. HTML5 could do something, but that is not supported by all browser either. OP should find another way to achieve what he/she wants.

Comment: What did people then do before HTML5 with the other browsers?

Comment: @Pierre: Are you serious? HTML5 isn't that old... anyway: people used sessions, cookies and hidden from fields (as a last resort)