# How to use ActiveXobject to support in other browsers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, activexobject

Currently, the below-sepecified javascript function is working fine with IE and the requirement is that I need to use the same function to display the content in other browsers too.

I'm aware that IE only supports ActiveX controls.
Could anyone please suggest the replacement of this function in javascript.

```
function show_packagemappings(target_letter) {
  // Load XML
  xml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
  xml.async=false;
  xml.load("xmldata\\map_packages.xml");

  xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");
  xslt.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction",true);
  xslt.async=false;
  xslt.load("packagemappings.xsl");


  xslTemp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");
  xslTemp.stylesheet = xslt;

  xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor();
  xslProc.input = xml;
  xslProc.addParameter("target_letter", target_letter);

  // Transform
  xslProc.transform;
  document.open()
  document.write(xslProc.output)
  document.close()
}
```

Comment: Why even you want to use ```ActiveXObject```. It is not used anywhere now and also has security issues. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject   and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087509/11926970

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for the ActiveX object for the other browsers excluding IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086761/alternative-for-the-activex-object-for-the-other-browsers-excluding-ie)

Comment: nope.
I need a function which can replace this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_packagemappings(target_letter)
{

    if (target_letter == '???') {
      document.getElementById("divElement").innerHTML = "";
      sessionStorage.target_letter = "";
      return;
    }

    sessionStorage.target_letter = target_letter;

    fn = "xmldata\\map_packages.xml"

    // console.log(fn);

    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {

      // Load XML
      xml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
      xml.async=false;
      xml.load(fn);

      if (xml.getElementsByTagName("target_letter")[0] == null) {
        var text = "<target_letter id='" + target_letter + "'>" 
                 + "<LastUpdate></LastUpdate>"
                 + "</target_letter>";

        var parser = new DOMParser();
        xml = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
      }

      console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName("target_letter")[0].getAttribute('id'));

      xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");
      xslt.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction",true);
      xslt.async=false;
      xslt.load("packagemappings.xsl");

      xslTemp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");
      xslTemp.stylesheet = xslt;

      xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor();
      xslProc.input = xml;
      xslProc.addParameter("target_letter", target_letter);

      // Transform
      xslProc.transform;
      document.getElementById("divElement").innerHTML = xslProc.output;

    }

    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {

      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.open("GET", fn);

      // via Cache-Control header:
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0");

      // fallbacks for IE and older browsers:
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Expires", "Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

      // Force the response to be parsed as XML
      xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

      xhttp.onload = function () {

        var xml;

        if (xhttp.readyState === xhttp.DONE && xhttp.status === 200) {
          xml = xhttp.responseXML;
        } else {
          var text = "<target_letter id='" + target_letter + "'>" 
                   + "<LastUpdate></LastUpdate>"
                   + "</target_letter>";

          var parser = new DOMParser();
          xml = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
        }

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", "packagemappings.xsl");

        // Force the response to be parsed as XML
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

        xhr.onload = function () {

          if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {

            var xsl = xhr.responseXML;

            xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
            xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,"target_letter",target_letter);
            resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            document.getElementById("divElement").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("divElement").appendChild(resultDocument);

          }
        }

        xhr.send("");

      };

      xhttp.send("");

    }

}
```